# Npm soap package - constructing XML request with WSSecurity instance header

Tags: node.js, api, soap, soap-client

I have a bit of problem with npm soap package. I don't know how to properly add attribute and value to password XML tag with this package.

What I need to do is to add this attribute:

```
Type="http://some-url"
```

to WSSecurity instance SOAP header:

```
<wsse:Password>SOME-PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
```

How can I achieve this effect with npm soap and it's WSSecurity instance?

This is the last thing I need in order for my API calls to be successful.

Answer (score 0):

What did you use to build the xml string request? I've used [xmlbuilder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlbuilder) and it works very well for me. Adding attribute start with `@` symbol.

```
builder.create({
  root: {
    xmlbuilder: {
      repo: {
        '@type': 'git', // attributes start with @ 
        '#text': 'git://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js.git' // text node 
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm not using any kind of additional builders. I'm using only soap package, it can do many great things, but the problem is that I just don't know what method of this package could help me with adding additional attribute to request. And this is exactly what I'm trying to find. Alternatively you could suggest different soap client which allows me to simply pass previously built XML as request. Because from this what I can see npm soap , doesn't allow to do that, it creates XML request for you, and allows you to modify it's specific parts.